# What is the most intuitive explanation for euler's identity?

Tags: exponential-function, constants

Is there any intuitive explanation for:
$$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$$

About whether this question is a duplicate, what is asked for is not a proof but an explanation that helps with the not-so-intuitive aspects of the identity.

Comment: $-1$ is one unit to the left ($\pi$ radians from the right, i.e. postive direction) of $0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "intuitive"?

Comment: I am open to any interpretation of the word.

Comment: If you think of $e^{i \theta}$ as a clockwise rotation of angle $\theta$ radians or remember  $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, then $e^{i \pi}$ is fairly obviously $-1$

Comment: See also [Has anyone talked themselves into understanding Euler's identity a bit?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72113/264)

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/727300/1) answer your question ?

Comment: That is an interesting explanation. Thanks Lucian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit vectors in the opposite direction along the real line in the complex plane add to zero.

[image]