# Derive Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$ and estimate $e$ in an elementary way

Tags: elementary-functions, eulers-number-e

Here is an elementary derivation (without calculus) of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$, although not a strict proof or derivation. My question is:

**Can we estimate the value of *e* in an elementary way?** I mean without calculus, just like we estimate $3<\pi<2\sqrt{3}$ (or more precise).

#### Step 1

For any positive real number *y* ≠ 1 (e.g. *y* = 10), we have $y^i=a+bi$, and we also have $y^{-i}=a-bi$. <sup>[1]</sup>

Because $1=y^{i}y^{-i}=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$, there should be a real number *x* matching $a=\cos{x}$ and $b=\sin{x}$. Then we get $y^i=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

This also means, for any real number *x* ≠ 0, there should be a real number *y* matching $y^i=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

So we can get the real number $e=y^{1/x}$ matching $e^{ix}=y^i=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$. (Although we don't know the exact value of *e* here, and *e* may be dependent on *x*.)

#### Step 2

Make *x* = 1, we get $e^i=\cos{1}+i\sin{1}$.

Then we generalize [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos{n}\theta+i\sin{n}\theta$ to non-integer powers $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^x=\cos{x}\theta+i\sin{x}\theta$. <sup>[2]</sup>

Make *θ* = 1, we get $(\cos{1}+i\sin{1})^x=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$, and finally we get $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

This means, the unique real number *e* (although we still don't know the value here) matches *x* = 1 and all other values.

#### Notes

[1] Here I use a rule of [Complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate):

> In general, if $\varphi$ is a holomorphic function whose restriction to the real numbers is real-valued, and $\varphi (z)$ and $\varphi (\overline {z})$ are defined, then
>
> $\varphi({\overline z})=\overline{\varphi(z)}$

This rule doesn't look elementary. However, we can accept it intuitively. According to the definition of imaginary number *i*<sup>2</sup> = −1, *i* can be replaced with -*i* in any equation, and vice versa.

[2] The generalization doesn't look elementary (may use some complex analysis) and may fail in some cases. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization).

---

I raised this question because I read [The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol. I Ch. 22: Algebra](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html) recently, where Feynman mentioned finally:

> We summarize with this, the most remarkable formula in mathematics:
>
> $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ (22.9)
>
> This is our jewel.

I think Feynman's derivation is redundant so I tried to derive it in a simple way beginning from de Moivre's formula.

Comment: Define elementary, would you be satisfied with the series definitions of $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$? You could use those to define $e^{i}$

Comment: You could define $e^{ix}$ as the solution to the IVP $$y''+y=0\\ y(0)=1 \\y'(0)=i$$

Comment: For an alternative viewpoint, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098929/question-regarding-eulers-form/4098949?r=SearchResults&s=1|16.0978#4098949).

Comment: @MatthewPilling You don't have to define that, you can simply DERIVE that by stating $y=e^{ix}$ and then take a derivative twice. This would indeed be my alternative approach for arriving at the OP's result

Comment: I don't think it can be done without calculus. It seems unreasonable to expect that topics from the Wiki link would suffice when complex numbers themselves aren't even included the link.

Comment: How do you even define $e$ without calculus?

Comment: You can't even formulate the claim using the mathematics from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_mathematics There are no complex numbers in there, let alone exponentiation with complex powers.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function $f(x)=\dfrac{\cos x+i\sin x}{e^{ix}}$. If you know the quotient rule, then $$f'(x)=\frac{e^{ix}(-\sin x+i\cos x)-(\cos x+i\sin x)\cdot ie^{ix}}{e^{2ix}}=0$$. Since the derivative of the function is $0$, therefore the function must be equal to some constant $C$. Therefore, $$\frac{\cos x+i\sin x}{e^{ix}}=C$$, where we can find the constant by putting $x=0$.
$$C=\frac{\cos 0+i\sin 0}{e^{0i}}=1$$.
Hence, the Euler's formula is proved.

---

I don't know if this matches your 'elementary' definition but this is an alternative way to using Maclaurin series.

Comment: I mean [Elementary Mathimatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_mathematics)

Comment: @auntyellow atleast you have to accept that high level mathematics can't be that much "elementary".

Comment: $f(x)=(\cos x+i\sin x)e^{-ix}$ may be more simple.